# Apply margin-right to divs with a sibling to their right or margin-left to divs with a sibling to their left

Tags: css

I have seven divs, five of them are small and two are large like below:

```
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='fullPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='fullPanel'>TEST</div>
```

CSS:

```
.halfPanel{
  width:48%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:48%;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:4%;
}

.fullPanel{
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:4%;
}
```

I need to put a gap after each halfPanel which has another halfPanel follows it to its right. But the challenge is that these seven panels are draggable and can be rearranged in any manner. I cannot add a new div wrapping two halfPanels or cannot use jQuery to do that. I need to implement this with pure css, without absolutely any change in HTML.

What I tried is:

```
div.halfPanel + div.halfPanel{
  margin-left:2%;
}
div.halfPanel + div.halfPanel+ div.halfPanel{
 margin-left:0%;
}

div.halfPanel + div.halfPanel+ div.halfPanel+div.halfPanel + div.halfPanel{
  margin-left:0%;
 }

div.halfPanel + div.halfPanel + div.halfPanel+ div.halfPanel{
  margin-left:2%;
}
```

But I know this is ugly css and is not at all scalable.
Is there any better way to achieve this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsabhi/k67tLd2n/) for what I implemented.

**EDIT:** I cannot use flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Dropped `.halfPanel` width to `47.5%` from `48%`.  See the code below or in 
[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/freginold/k67tLd2n/2/) for a working solution.  Works with any number of full and half panels as far as I can tell.

```css
.halfPanel{
  width:47.5%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:48%;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:4%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.fullPanel{
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:4%;
}
```

```html
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='fullPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='fullPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='fullPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
```

Comment: Breaks in this case: `<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='fullPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
`

Comment: Ah, crud. Thanks @gaganshera.

Comment: @gaganshera Thanks you were too close but as gaganshera pointed out it breaks in that case

Comment: @PassionateProgrammer Still working on it... this is definitely an interesting one!

Comment: @freginold Yes it is and I am also trying.. Thanks a lot for taking interest on this. I still strongly believe that there is a pure CSS way for it

Comment: @PassionateProgrammer The gap has to be the 2% that you have, right?

Comment: @freginold the gap should be 4% in total. The two halfPanels width totals upto 96%. So remaining 4% should be the gap

Comment: @PassionateProgrammer In the CSS that you used above, it only adds a 2% margin.  If you change it to 4%, or put 2% on the other side, it runs off the line.

Comment: O.K 2% is enough

Comment: @PassionateProgrammer OK. FYI If you want to drop it to 1.5% I've got a working solution.

Comment: @PassionateProgrammer Or if you can change the width to 47.5% instead of 48%, then it would work, too.

Comment: @freginold Sorry I was travelling. I am very much exited to see thee working solution. I can surely drop the margin to 47.5%. Please share it.

Comment: @PassionateProgrammer I updated my answer to show a working solution with the `.halfPanel` blocks at 47.5% instead of 48%.

Comment: @freginold I can't believe this! How can the solution be so simple!.

Comment: @freginold I dropped the fullPanel width to 97% to align the div endings and it now seems to be perfect. Hat's off to your passion and determination!

Answer (score 2):

The sibling combinator selector might work for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/w2rwbjd7/

```
div.halfPanel:first-child {
  border-color: red;
}

div.halfPanel ~ div.halfPanel {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Note: Used `border-color` for immediate clarity of what is affected by selectors.

Comment: I am not sure whether I reused your css rules with margins correctly... please check the fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/bzn217mz/1/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.halfPanel{
  width:48%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:48%;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:4%;
}
.fullPanel{
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:4%;
}
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='fullPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='fullPanel'>TEST</div>


<span> Using Flex box (resize browser) </span>

<div class="test">
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='halfPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='fullPanel'>TEST</div>
<div class='fullPanel'>TEST</div>
</div>
```

You can try the :nth(even). Sample below and Another sample with flexbox

Comment: Sorry I cannot use flexbox